# Python Problem Take input N from the user Print 'EVEN' for every even number Print 'ODD' for every odd number, from 1 to N

Tags: python, numbers

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIq9N.png)Even Numbers!

Take input N from the user and print `EVEN` for every even number and `ODD` for every odd number between 1 and N.

Sample Input 1:

```
4
```

Sample Output 1:

```
ODD
EVEN
ODD
EVEN
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the modulus opperator which is % in python to check if the number is odd or even.

```
N = int(input("Enter a number: "))
i = 1
while(i <= N):
    if (i % 2) == 0:
        print('EVEN')
    else:
        print('ODD')

    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

N = int(input())

for i in range(1,N+1):

if i%2 == 0:

```
     print("EVEN".format(i))
```

else:

```
    print("ODD".format(i))
```